# How filter dataframe by groupby second column in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, filter, group-by, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I have a df with the columns, 'households, people, flag', and would like to filter the dataframe to households that contain at least one flag. I understand the logic but am not sure how to code it, can someone help? For the example below, the output would remove household 2.

logic:
`df = df.filter(all rows in households where at least one row in that household contains 'flag'==1)`

```
Example dataframe:
| Household| Person|flag|
| -------- | ----- | -- |
| 1        | Oliver|    |
| 1        | Jonny | 1  | 
| 2        | David |    |
| 2        | Mary  |    |
| 3        | Lizzie|    |
| 3        | Peter | 1  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter and `groupBy` to get the desired `Household` and do inner join to get the final reault.

```
df.join(df.filter("flag = '1'").select('Household').distinct(), ['Household'], 'inner').show()

+---------+------+----+
|Household|Person|flag|
+---------+------+----+
|        1|Oliver|null|
|        1| Jonny|   1|
|        3|Lizzie|null|
|        3| Peter|   1|
+---------+------+----+
```